# castle windsor with .net 4.0 ,iis 7.5

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

In my application I used .net 4.0,iis 7.0 and castle windsor old version.
Now I am moving this app to new machine with only changing iis 7.0 to 7.5.

But when I deployed app on new server Its not working its giving applicaion error.

Error Details.

```
Error Message :The type name Platform.Data.VisualDao, Platform.Data could not be located    
Stack Trace :   at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.ObtainType(String typeName)
   at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUpComponents(IConfiguration[] configurations, IWindsorContainer container)
   at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUp(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.RunInstaller()
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer..ctor(IConfigurationInterpreter interpreter)
   at Platform.Data.DaoFactory..cctor() in D:\DaoFactory.cs:line 21  
Base Exception : System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The type name Platform.Data.VisualDao, Platform.Data could not be located
   at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.ObtainType(String typeName)
   at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUpComponents(IConfiguration[] configurations, IWindsorContainer container)
   at Castle.Windsor.Installer.DefaultComponentInstaller.SetUp(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.RunInstaller()
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer..ctor(IConfigurationInterpreter interpreter)
   at Platform.Data.DaoFactory..cctor() in D:DaoFactory.cs:line 21
```

Code:

```
internal class DaoFactory : IDaoFactory    
    {
        static  ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("DaoFActory");
        private readonly static Dictionary<Type, object> _daoRegistry;

        static DaoFactory()
          {
            _logger.Debug("Starting cctor");  

                // TODO Implement this Dynamically                
                string daoConfigFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["daoComponents"];
                _logger.Debug("Path"+daoConfigFile);

                _logger.Debug("Initilizing container");  
                IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(daoConfigFile));

                _logger.Debug("Initilized....Creating reg");  
                _daoRegistry = new Dictionary<Type, object>();


                _daoRegistry[typeof(IPMUserDao)] = container.Resolve("pmUserDao");
                _daoRegistry[typeof(IPMRoleDao)] = container.Resolve("pmRoleDao");
}
}
```

I am getting exception when i am initilizing container :

IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(daoConfigFile));

daoConfigfile is path of xml file from where I am getting Platform.data

platform.data is available in bin folder.

Please help me to solve this....

Comment: Most possibly the error is in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a config problem.  It could be either a simple casing issue or incorrect component declaration.

Comment: any idea how to DEBUG it?